# How to pass string types while using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am using map method like below in typescript and react.

```
const final = result.map(({id,name}) => ({id, name}));
```

here i get type error "binding element id has implicitly any type"
"binding element name has implicitly any type"

here id and name are string. how can i specify that here

i have tried doing

```
const final = result.map(({id: string, name:string}) => ({id, name}));
```

but this doesnt seem to be right.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

I am new to typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the types when destructuring like so:

```
const final = result.map(({id, name}: {id: string, name: string}) => ({id, name}));
```

Or you can create an interface for it and set that as the object you are destructuring

```
interface User {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

const final = result.map(({id, name}: User) => ({id, name}))
```